# Unix not checking file permissions properly

Tags: file, unix, permissions

I executed the following commands in unix machine:

```
blr59-adm1:~ # ls -l / | grep back
d-w--w--w-   2 root root  4096 Jun  9 13:31 backupmnt
blr59-adm1:~ # [ -x /backupmnt ]
blr59-adm1:~ # echo $?
0
blr59-adm1:~ #
```

I am not able to get why I am getting the output of `echo $?` as `0` even if my directory is not having execute permissions.

My shell script is failing because of this behavior.

Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems that your are logged as `root` (the `#` prompt is an indicator of this), so as a being a super-user your are authorized to do almost everything, in particular going through any directory whatever permissions say.